# How do I find out of a certain character is the first or second or third occurrence in a string?

Tags: java

If I had a string like "telephone" and wanted the output to come back as tel*phon*, how would I do that?

The program would print back out each letter in the string. If it's the first time that letter is appearing then I'd write it. But if it reappears, I would print an asterisk.

hello would be hel*o

goodbye would be go*dbye

coordination would be co*rdinat***  (oops you're right)

Please help thanks! And this is not homework... this is practice for the final coming up! Thanks!!

I'm trying something like... but I just don't get how to get further... Please help

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String s;
int i, j, count;
System.out.print("Enter string: ");
s = keyboard.nextLine();



for(i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
   count = 0;
   for(j=i+1; i < s.length(); j++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)){
           count++;
        }
        if(count < 1)
           System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        else
           System.out.print("*");
   }
}
```

Some told me to post my code so I did now. How would I edit this exact code to make it work? Please help :(

Comment: wouldn't coordination be co*rdinat***? Also, check out `Set<E>`.

Comment: refer to API doc and `replace()` method

Comment: Do it on a sheet of paper with a pencil. Try to find a recipe for what you are doing. This recipe is called algorithm. Try to translate the algorithm to java. If you still have problems then, come back here and post your code!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a convenient way to do it.  `Set` has a boolean property on `add()`, which returns false if the value is already inserted into the set.

**Approach**:  Create a data structure such that you can guarantee only unique values are ever inserted into it.  If a unique value is inserted into it, then it's fine to keep building out your return string.  If not, then you need to generate the asterisk instead.

Reference the code below.  To guarantee an unbiased treatment of upper-case vs. lower case characters, call `toLowerCase()` before `.toCharArray()`.

```
public static String filterChars(final String word) {
    final Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(Character c : word.toCharArray()) {
        if(set.add(c)) {
            builder.append(c);
        } else {
            builder.append('*');
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<Character>();
String result = "";
for (char ch : input.toCharArray())
{
    if (seen.contains(ch))
        result += "*";
    else
    {
        result += ch;
        seen.add(ch);
    }
}
```

`input` is the input string, and `result` is the output string.

Basically this goes through each character in the input string and appends the appropriate character to a result string based on whether the character was seen already or not.

Comment: @Dylan Thank you. I wrote this without any Java compiler in front of me, so I was just guessing that it would work. :)

Comment: :D It gets confusing between all of these different languages, and I really wish that Java had such a feature in for loops. It is even extended from C, but it **still** can't iterate over an String. It's not that difficult to fix, but it does (it did for me) cause confusion. Thanks for changing it!