# How do I replace all but one occurrence of a certain character?

Tags: java

If I had a string like `telephone` and wanted the output to come back as `tel*phon*`, how would I do that?

The program would print back out each letter in the string. If it's the first time that letter is appearing then I'd write it. But if it reappears, I would print an asterisk.

`hello` would be `hel*o`

`goodbye` would be `go*dbye`

`coordination` would be `co*rdinat***`

Please help thanks! And this is not homework... this is practice for the final coming up! Thanks!!

I'm trying something like this... but I just don't get how to get further... Please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class firstOccurrence{ 
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String s;
      int i, j, count;
      System.out.print("Enter string: ");
      s = keyboard.nextLine();



      for(i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
         count = 0;
         for(j = i+1; i < s.length(); j++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j))
               count++;
         }

         if(count < 1)
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
         else
            System.out.print("*");
      }
   }
}
```

How would I edit this exact code to make it work? Please help :(

Comment: Time to learn regular expressions!

Comment: for each char, check to see if it is contained in a `List`.  If not contained, print it, add it to the list.  If yes printout '*' instead.

Comment: @Unihedron Our teacher didn't teach us regular expressions. Basically we should be able to do this program without any of that.

Comment: Please show an example of the input and output for the given code, and also wrap the code in a `main` so we can compile it. BTW, @blurfus`s hint is a good one.

Comment: Your approach looks OK except for the second `for`, and your `if` statement that prints out the character is in the wrong place.  Start with the `for`.  If `i = 5`, for example, which characters do you want to look at in your `for (j = ...)` loop?

Comment: @ajb Thanks to all. But ajb the only one I'm close to understanding . Do you mean I should put the j loop right under the i loop? I put that count = 0 between them because I want the count to become 0 everytime i is incremented. And if i = 5...I would want j to start at 6 and go up to s.length(). But you see this is what confuses me. I just want the letter to be printed out if it's the first occurrence. i just don't get how to make the program do that...like such and such is the first occurrence so print the letter and that such and such is the 2nd occurrence, therefore print "*" :/

Comment: you don't need lists and regular expressions. As @ajb said, the problem is in the inner loop. You're very close to make it work.

Comment: blurfus's comment should help, but I would suggest using a boolean array to keep track of visited characters (256 long), since it is much faster and could be more space efficient than the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out of a certain character is the first or second or third occurrence in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149353/how-do-i-find-out-of-a-certain-character-is-the-first-or-second-or-third-occurre)

Comment: @FarahJaved If `i` is 5, do you really want to count the matching characters from 6 to the end?  That means that if the string is `"understands"`, so that character 5 is `s`, then your count would be 1 because you'd be counting the last `s` in the string, and the result is that the _first_ `s` would be replaced by `*` instead of the last one.

Comment: @ajb so that it will work with all types of characters. You can hack it into 26 long if you want by subtracting the char encoding offsets of the letters.

Comment: @nmore "All types of characters"?  Including all the letters from the Russian, Greek, Tamil, Armenian, Ogham, etc., etc., etc. alphabets?  Characters in Java are 16 bits wide so your boolean array would have to be 65536, not 256.

Comment: @ajib you are totally correct, had a brain fart. So to clarify, it should be 26 long, and then you can subtract the char encoding offsets of the letters to index into the array. Then in this case you have to worry about upper and lower case letters if you have to handle them differently.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String s;
System.out.print("Enter string: ");

s = keyboard.nextLine();

Set<Character> occur=new HashSet<Character>();

StringBuilder stb=new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

    if(occur.contains(s.charAt(i)))
        stb.append("*");
    else
        stb.append(s.charAt(i));

    occur.add(s.charAt(i));         

}

System.out.println(stb.toString());
```

Use This Code, it is way more decent for two reasons:

- use StringBuilder because your String is mutable
- use set to add unique elements characters

PS:Code is already Tested

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward approach to solving this problem is given in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150653/1441122). It iterates over each character of the input string and builds up a set of characters seen so far, building up an output `StringBuilder` with the current character or its replacement if the current character has been seen already.

This problem seems like it ought to be amenable to Java 8 streams processing. There's a new function `String.chars()` which converts a `String` into a `Stream` of `char`. (There's no `CharStream`, though, so each `char` is represented as an `int` and the stream type is `IntStream`.

To do this, though, we want to write a mapper function that potentially replaces a character with a replacement character, but only if that character has been seen already. We thus want a *stateful mapper* function, which is a bit unusual. It's not too difficult to write one using a higher-order function, though:

```
public static IntUnaryOperator replaceIfSeen(int replacement) {
    Map<Integer,Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return i -> seen.putIfAbsent(i, Boolean.TRUE) == null ? i : replacement;
}
```

The processing is essentially the same, except it's wrapped up differently. The `replaceIfSeen` function *returns* a mapper function that builds up the seen characters in a map. (There's no `ConcurrentHashSet` so we use a map instead, but it's basically the same.) The mapper function returns the input character if it's encountered for the first time, or it returns the replacement character if it's already been encountered. It's used like this:

```
static String replace(String input) {
    return input.chars()
        .map(replaceIfSeen('*'))
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char)i))
        .collect(joining());
}
```

We take the input string and turn it into a stream of char (represented as `int`) and call our conditional mapper function on it, asking it to replace duplicates with the `*` character. The `mapToObj` operation is a bit of a wrinkle, as we need to convert the `char` portion of an `int` into a one-character String. Then we collect and join those one-character strings into the output. The results are as expected by the OP.

Note that this behaves differently if the stream is run in parallel. It still *works*, sort of, in that there is exactly one occurrence of any given character, with all others replaced with `*`. The difference is that the character that isn't replaced might not be the first. For example, given the input string `coordination` the result might be `c**rd*natio*`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **regex approach** to solve this problem, one that can work without using any external container to keep track of replacements:

```
String s = "coordination";
while(s.matches(".*?(\\w)(?=.*?\\1).*")) {
    s = s.replaceAll("(?<=(\\w))((?:(?!\\1).)*)\\1", "$2*");
}
System.out.println( s );
//=> co*rdinat***
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD1eR3/2)

**explanation:**

- While loop is used to repeat the replacements as long as there are more than one duplicate characters.
- This regex uses a **zero-width lookbehind** to capture the letter in first captured group `(?<=(\\w))`.
- `((?:(?!\\1).)*)` will match all word characters except the first captured letter
- `\\1` matches next occurrence of the captured letter in group #1
- Mode details about this regex are available in provided demo link on `regex101`